# How to render html content containing svg using Itext without manipulating the html

Tags: svg, pdf-generation, itext

I am using **Itext** to render the HTML content into pdf. Because of the presence of **svg** elements together with other html elements, the Itext rendering is not working properly. I am aware of rendering svg alone using itext.

But I am wondering if there is a way so that I can render the whole **html content with svg**  into a PDF using Itext *without manipulating the html content by myself*?

Already there is a question addressing the same issue but I am not able to solve my problem from this. If you understand the solution from this link then please explain.
[Java/iText/Flying Saucer: Convert HTML containing svg tags to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437234/java-itext-flying-saucer-convert-html-containing-svg-tags-to-pdf)

Comment: SVG parsing isn't supported in iText's XML Worker.

Comment: But is there any other library which we integrate with Itext,  so that it can support the html containing both svg and other html elements?